# How to define the col names BEFORE making an empty Data Frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make an *empty* data frame df (0-rows),
with 2 column names: **"A"** and **"B"**.
This is a simple example. There could be hundreds of column names... 
(rows will be added later  with number values 0 to 1 - ie: 0.80 0.20).

Will first show what I have (works ok),
and then what I need, (but don't know how to do it!).

This is what I HAVE and it works ok:

> df <- data.frame("A" = numeric() , "B" = numeric(), 
>    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
>
> df
>   [1] A B
>   <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

but, 
I NEED to define the col names:
   **"A"** and **"B"**
*outside and before* the call to:
      df <- data.frame(...).

Like this:

> **colnames** <- c("A" "B")
>   df <- data.frame(**colnames**,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
>
> df

colnames
    1        A
    2        B

wrong df!...what I need is:
(simulated needed empty df, just like 1st example above)

> df
>   [1] A B
>   <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

How do I do specify the column names in **colnames**
*before* generating the empty data frame df?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a workaround, but should work for you:

```
colnames <- c("A","B")

l <- list()
l[[ colnames[1] ]] <- NA
l[[ colnames[2] ]] <- NA

df <- as.data.frame(l)
df <- df[ -1, ]

> str(df)
[1] A B
<0 rows> (or row.names with length 0)
```

A shorter version is the following:

```
colnames <- c("A","B")

d <- c(NA,NA)
names(d) <- colnames
df <- data.frame(rbind(d))[-1,]
```

Have fun!

Comment: thks Seily!  but you see? I need to define the 2 col names "A" and "B"  BEFORE the call to df=data.frame(...).   Take a look at my NEED example above.

Comment: sry! I just corrected the answer! It is a little late ;o) This should work for you now.

Comment: Thks Seily. Saw your correction. It works. But isn't there a simpler way to do it without defining a list first? Without so many intermediate steps?... I'm trying to use colnames directly INSIDE the call to: df=data.frame(...colnames here! inside.....). All done in only 2 steps: 1) define colnames then 2) define df =data.frame(...using colnames...).

Comment: Great job, Seily! Thanks / Danke! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since OP asked for a short way to do this, here is a one-liner (after the colnames have been previously defined) that returns a data frame with zero rows and the desired column names.

```
colnames <- c('A', 'B')
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2)), nm = colnames)
```